# QR code not decoded same string two formats

Tags: java, android, zxing

We have the string `117355|1.3,-0.6|1.68,1.25|2.95,-0.6|1.68,1.25`encoded into a QR code. We have been using an online generator. The generator has produced two variations, shown here:

This one is easily decoded by our app.

[image: Working Version]

This one returns the `ChecksumException`

[image: Non-decoding Version]

Both scan fine when using a 3rd party scanning app, however, we are using the ZXING library within our app and instead of using a video feed we are using a still image, so one attempt, this is due to this being part of a wider image processing workflow.

The reason I said "two formats" is due to the sections of each QR code being different according to this. We have different strings and whenever we have the "3 dots" under the top right registration marker it scans, and when we don't the scan is unreliable.

[image]

Here is the reading section of code:

```
    QRCodeReader reader;
    try {
        reader = new QRCodeReader();
        Map<DecodeHintType, Object> tmpHintsMap = new EnumMap<DecodeHintType, Object>(DecodeHintType.class);
        tmpHintsMap.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);

        BinaryBitmap img = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(
                new GreyscaleLuminanceSource(greyscaleHalf, w, h)));
        Result scanResult = reader.decode(img, tmpHintsMap);
        return scanResult;
    } catch (ChecksumException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        mError = "The QR Code could not be decoded";
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
        mError = "The QR Code could not be found";
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FormatException e) {
        mError = "The QR Code Format";
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
```

As you can see I have tried the `DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER` option, but this does not help. We were working with 3.2.0 and I have recently tried with 3.2.1.

We have had 22,000 of these labels printed and I need to find a solution to make this scan reliably.

Comment: Using the online zxing.org decoder both images can be decoded: [QR code 1](https://zxing.org/w/decode?u=http%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FX2LAp.png) and [QR code 2](https://zxing.org/w/decode?u=http%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FsJjxe.png). May be the one QR code has more redundancy and is therefore easier to decode?

Comment: @robert how can I change my code to code it?

Comment: I think it is not a problem of your code more the camera/photo quality and the light situation while scanning the QR code.